# Extract a single line of text from an email

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to get one sentence from a lot of HTML emails. The sentence is located in the exact same place in every email (including the same line if you view the source code).

So far I have used `imaplib` to set up the connection to the correct mailbox, search and  fetch the body of the email.

```
response_code_fetch, data_fetch = mail.fetch('1', '(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])')
if response_code_fetch == "OK":
    print("Body Text: " + str(data_fetch[0]))
else:
    print("Unable to find requested messages")
```

However, I get an incoherent list that has the entire body of the email at index `[0]` of the returned list. I've tried `str(data_fetch[0])` and then using the `splitlines` method, but it doesn't work.

I've also found the below suggestion online using the `email` module, but it doesn't seem to work as it prints the else statement.

```
my_email = email.message_from_string(data_fetch)
body = ""
if my_email.is_multipart():
    for part in my_email.walk():
        ctype = part.get_content_type()
        cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))
        print(ctype, cdispo)

# not multipart - i.e. plain text, no attachments, keeping fingers crossed
else:
    print("Email is not multipart")
    body = my_email.get_payload(decode=True)
    print(body)
```

I won't include the whole result as it's very long but it basically looks like I get the code for the email, HTML formatting, body text and all:

```
Body Text: [(b'1 (BODY[TEXT] {78687}', b'--_av-
uaAIyctTRCxY0f6Fw54pvw\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-
8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n
```

Does anyone know how can I get the one sentence out of the body text?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `b` in front of your string makes it a a [byte literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal). What if you put a `.decode('UTF-8')` behind your `Body Text` string?